# How to get ArrayList elements enclosed in single quote using C#.NET

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, arraylist

I have an ArrayList named 'ssArray9'. It contains elements like
{R1,R2,R3,R4}. I want the arraylist elements to be enclosed in single quote in a string variable as

```
var subSecCdStr = "'R1','R2','R3','R4'";
```

Currently i'm using the below mentioned code but it doesn't give desired output.

```
var subSecCdStr = string.Join("','", (string[])ssArray9.ToArray("".GetType()));
```

The output is like : `R1','R2`

Please advise how to format the string in desired format? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format individual items to put single quotes around them. With C# 6 you can do it like this:

```
var subSecCdStr = string.Join(",", ssArray9.Select(x => $"'{x}'"));
```

If you use an earlier version of the language, you could use `string.Format` instead:

```
var subSecCdStr = string.Join(",", ssArray9.Cast<string>.Select(x => string.Format("'{0}'", x)));
```

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.5. When i use the code as suggested above, .NET IDE intellisense shows an error saying that 'ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'Select'. Am i missing any namespace??

Comment: @user1448677 If `ssArray9` is not generic, you need to add `Cast<object>()` call before `Select`.

Comment: var subSecCdStr = string.Join(",", ssArray9.Cast<object>().Select(x => string.Format("'{0}'", x.GetType()))); The output of the above is like 'System.String','System.String'